# Polymer renders a blank page in WAMP or using Python

Tags: python, wamp, wampserver, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm new to Polymer and I'm using WAMP to host my Polymer 1.0 project in my local host. I've seen other questions in this topic but none of the answers helped me as I'm still getting blank page with no errors (or warnings) in Chrome browser. The only thing I get is something which looks like a grey bar at the top of the page.

I'm following [this tutorial in Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMtnllatakc&index=3&list=PLPaj_o9gjMYll0sSb47TrzQCjIo5iqQZm).

I've actually tried that using Python on localhost:8000 and I get the same thing, so I suspect something is wrong with my code.

**Note 1:** if I only have a `<paper-input>` element with its declaration, it works fine.

**Note 2:** the code actually worked in the beginning, but as I started to do some experiments(!!!) and then the page started to render blank with no errors! strange!

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
</head>

<body class="vertical layout" style="background-color: #dddddd;">
    <paper-header-panel>
        <paper-material style="background-color: #ffffff;">
            <paper-toolbar>
                <div>Example My Polymer</div>
            </paper-toolbar>

            <h3>This is my content 1</h3>

            <p>Hello</p>
        </paper-material>
    </paper-header-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure all the components are actually downloaded?

Comment: Yes, I ran `bower update` a few times on the folder, and as I said I was able to see what I suppose to see in the browser once or twice first. Also while running all the gets for those files are fine (200) and no errors on chrome dev tools whatsoever.

Comment: Thought to mention, and I also have the most recent version of bower and npm!

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer or XAMPP?

Comment: WAMP it is. On Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Okay! :( Not sure if bower is complaining about anything in your case. But I had an issue where some components didn't render properly because they were relying on another version of some components. What I did was; remove the dependencies lines in the "main" bower.json and then ran `bower update`, which force-updated all my components to the latest versions. (Since neither python or wamp seem to work I would think it's something with the Polymer setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue when using [paper-header-panel](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-header-panel)

> Important: The paper-header-panel will not display if its parent does not have a height.

Make your body (the paper-head-panel's parent) take up the full page height:

```
<body class="fullbleed">
```

Comment: Thanks :) just to mention that `/bower_components/paper-styles/classes/shadow-layout.html` is needed to be imported for `fullbleed` to work as the CSS class is defined in the shadow-layout.html